# Stop Umbraco form stealing internal links

Tags: umbraco

Sometimes I want to write the entire link to a page, which can be good if in example a visitor wants to print the page or just copy the url from the web site. The thing is if I write http://www.mysite.com/licensing/terms ubmraco cuts that and removes the http://www.mysite.com, both from the link it self and from the text.

Ie

```
<a href="/licensig/terms">/licensig/terms</a>
```

What i want is that it should remain as

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/licensing/terms">http://www.mysite.com/licensing/terms</a>
```

It does not matter if i write the link in the source editor, if i write it in the html source editor or if I use the link tool in the rich text editor.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I can see why you may want to keep the domain in the text visible to the user (`<a href="...">licencing terms</a>` would be better though, both for the user and for search engines), but why would you want to restrict the link to this domain when you could simply make it independent of the protocol and exact domain under which your website is available? Leave it like this and the link survives domain changes, addition of HTTPS, and propably a few other things.

Comment: Usually it's fine as you say, but this time I host several subdomains in Umbraco which messes stuff up. In the described case i actually try to link to http://www.mysite.com/licensing/terms from a site called http://docs.mysite.com/. It still renders a link called /licensing/terms which is broken. So its a bug which I'll report when i have some more time! :)

Comment: I have the same problem, see http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/7697-Cannon-enter-full-URL-in-text-in-tinyMCE but have not found a solution yet.

Comment: Andreas, If you do please keep med posted

Answer (score 1):

Use `umbraco.library:NiceUrlFullPath($currentPage/@id)` in your XSLT to get the full domain and protocol included in your URL, or `umbraco.library.NiceUrlFullPath(Node.GetCurrent().Id)` in a usercontrol code-behind or binding.

HTH,

Benjamin